# Simplify the code to flatten arrays in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose I have a 1000x2x10x10 matrix, and currently I put them into two cell arrays by the following code,

```
  for i=1:1000
    tmp = seqs(i,1,:);
    patterns{i} = tmp(:);
    tmp = seqs(i,2,:);
    labels{i} = tmp(:);
  end
```

The purpose of `patterns{i} = tmp(:)` and `labels{i} = tmp(:)` is to flatten the matrix. My question is that, is it possible to simplify the code like `patterns{i}=seqs(i,1,:)(:)`? I tried this one but Matlab does not allow this, and that's why I currently have to use a temporary variable `tmp`.

Comment: You can use `patterns{i}=reshape(seqs(i,1,:),[],1);` to reshape into a column like `(:)` does. Also, your code can probably simplified with `mat2cell`, but I'm not sure what the snippet is doing. Maybe post a minimal example with desired input and output

Comment: I normally have a separate function on my computer called `vec` which does this operation. To answer your question there is no way to do that without doing another memory call in Matlab via some function such as reshape or whatnot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just give you 3 ways to do this. All of which work.

The first is the one I normally use is to have a function on my computer called `vec`

```
function out = vec(in)
out = in(:);
end
```

and then you can use it via

```
patterns{i} = vec(seqs(i,1,:));
```

Then you can call this function and it allows for more streamlined code. The second is reshape mentioned in the comments

```
patterns{i}=reshape(seqs(i,1,:),[],1);
```

I typically don't recommend reshape for these types of problems because it tends to fail if you aren't careful. The last is to use squeeze and transpose.

```
patterns{i} = squeeze(seqs(i,1,:))';
```

Personally, I prefer the first because it makes my code look nicer.

Comment: Or you do `vec = @(in) in(:);` somewhere in the program before you need `vec`. Then you don’t need the separate file.

Comment: _I typically don't recommend reshape for these types of problems because it tends to fail if you aren't careful_ What do you mean? When does `reshape(...,[],1)` fail?

Comment: Also, note that `'` transposes _and conjugates_